# How to trigger the event of a table cell dynamically added through Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a table with rows generated through jquery, and I want the temperature column to auto update and get its latest value through an http request.

So in order to select those cells, since they're dynamically generated, I used `.on()` and it works fine with events like `click` and `mouseenter`.

But since there are multiple rows, I thought I would use something like `setInterval`, but it's not working and I don't know why, event without the set interval or a custom event.

After searching similar issues, I suspect that `trigger()` doesn't work well with elements added with jQuery. So any ideas on how I can get around this so that the cell value is updated?

Here's the relevant bit of code:

```
    <p id='showData'>
     <table id="display-table" class="display-table"></table>
    </p>
```

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      DisplayList();
      
      $("table").on('mouseenter', ".temp", function(){
        var cellTemp = this;
        console.log("this is :" +here.id);
        console.log(ceci);
        UpdateTemp(cellTemp.id, cellTemp.id, cellTemp.className).then(function(value){
          cellTemp.innerHTML=(value);
        });
      });
      
      $(document).on('test', '.name', function () { alert("hello"); });
      
      $("table").trigger('mouseenter');
    });
```

Comment: _“I suspect that trigger() doesn't work well with elements added with jQuery”_ - I don’t think that is the issue here (or actually one in general.) The problem here is likely rather that you are _reacting_ on mousover events for individiual cells, but you want to trigger the event for the table itself - I don’t think that is supposed to work, resp. I can’t see what sense that would make. You would have to trigger the event on each cell individually.

Comment: If you're calling `.trigger("mouseenter")` to initialise your `UpdateTemp` - then just pull the code out into a function and call it directly.

Comment: There's no issue with .trigger on dynamically created events - the issue is that you're using event delegation to *filter those events to specific elements* (ie `.temp`) - so your `mouseenter` doesn't trigger your event handler because the event handler is expecting it to fire against `.temp` but it's firing against the table.   You *could* do `$("table .temp:first").trigger('mouseenter');` to run an init, but it's not clear that's what you want - again, looks like it would be better off pulled into a separate function, then you can loop.   Not sure what `setInterval` has to do with anything.